# Summing Variables Using For-each-group

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a list of nodes for which I need to compute a total then sum said total as a group. I have created the appropriate variables but when I use a sum() as my final output, it produces a concatenated string as opposed to a total value.

Here is the input XML:

```xml
<LineItems>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>105.28</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>75</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>2.88</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>3</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>155.36</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>12</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>1.64</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>2</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>2.28</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>5</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>3.6</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>405.24</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>5</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>79.04</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>2.15</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>9</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>2.15</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
    </LineItems>
```

And here is what I have been using thus far:

```xml
<tpi:Fact name="TotalLinePrice" factType="Virtual">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="/PurchaseOrder/LineItems/LineItem/OrderLine" group-starting-with="OrderLine[normalize-space(OrderQty)]">
                    <xsl:variable name="uPrice" as="node()*">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:variable name="unitPrice">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="xs:decimal(current-group()/UnitPrice)"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:variable name="orderQty">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="xs:decimal(current-group()/OrderQty)"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:variable name="calcPriceBasis">
                            <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='TP']">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 1000))"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='HT']">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 1000))"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='HP']">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 100))"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='HTH']">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 100000))"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='PD']">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 12))"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='PN']">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 10))"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='TT']">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 10000))"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="$unitPrice"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <total>
                            <xsl:sequence select="format-number($calcPriceBasis * $orderQty, '0.00')"/>
                        </total>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum($uPrice)"/>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </tpi:Fact>
```

The output I am getting is:

```
"TOTALLINEPRICE":"105.28216466.0819.684.5618405.24395.22.1519.35"
```

which is each node of this calculation

```
<xsl:sequence select="format-number($calcPriceBasis * $orderQty, '0.00')"/>
```

appended to itself as a concatenated string.
But I would hope to see

```
"TOTALLINEPRICE": "1456.84"
```

which would be the sum total of each calculated value.

TOTALLINEPRICE is a new node created inside of the XML much like adding

```
<TOTALLINEPRICE>
</TOTALLINEPRICE>
```

As you can see, I need to compute a different price basis based on an input code (UnitPriceBasis) within each nodes itself. I know that xslt is not a programmatic language and variables are technically immutable. But there has to be a way to do this.

For reference, I am using:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:tpi="http://www.spscommerce.net/tpi">
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Well, I would suggest to reduce samples to a minimum but keep them complete to demonstrate that particular issue, if you have a couple of items you group want the sum and want a particular value then show us the sample data with those particular items allowing anyone to compute the sum and tell us which value you expect for your sample data. I see a single `OrderLine` in your XML sample with `<UnitPrice>105.28</UnitPrice>`, where `105.28` seems to part of the concatenated data you complain about. Is any of the other wrong data in the sample so that we could tell where it comes from?

Comment: Also where is `"TOTALLINEPRICE":"105.28216466.0819.684.5618405.24395.22.1519.35"` supposed to be output in your code, I don't see any of that in terms of normal XSLT processing, there is some result element with e.g. a name attribute `tpi:Fact name="TotalLinePrice"` but it is not clear what your output has to do with the XSLT or what additional tool you use.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. not snippets of code taken out context.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for the feedback. I have consolidated the base XML to make it more readable. I need to use those three input params to calculate a value that I store as a variable. TOTALLINEPRICE is a fact that we transmit as a node to Snowflake via Firehose. Essentially, I need it to be total aggregated value for all Line Item totals based on the computed values. Does that make sense?

Comment: @michael.hor257k How is the code taken out of context? I am simply asking how to sum XSLT variables stored inside of a for-each-group.

Comment: Please provide an input sample and an XSLT sample, both minimal but complete, together with the XSLT result you want and the one you get. I don't know what Snowflake or Firehose is and what their relation is to the XSLT code, so if you can only present the result in terms of those tools then add a tag for them and see whether someone in that context understands the sample input, XSLT, and result.

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't. That doesn't mean that you cannot get the result you want from the input you have. But I cannot tell you how, because I see neither. Please read this link carefully: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following **simplified** example:

**XML**

```
<items>
    <item>
        <qty>2</qty>
        <price>10.00</price>
        <group>A</group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <qty>3</qty>
        <price>5.00</price>
        <group>A</group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <qty>4</qty>
        <price>8.00</price>
        <group>A</group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <qty>6</qty>
        <price>3.00</price>
        <group>B</group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <qty>3</qty>
        <price>9.00</price>
        <group>B</group>
    </item>
    <item>
        <qty>7</qty>
        <price>8.00</price>
        <group>C</group>
    </item>
 </items>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/items">
    <xsl:variable name="subtotals">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="group">
            <subtotal group="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/(price*qty))"/>
            </subtotal>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
    <output>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$subtotals"/>
        <total>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($subtotals/subtotal)"/>
        </total>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <subtotal group="A">67</subtotal>
   <subtotal group="B">45</subtotal>
   <subtotal group="C">56</subtotal>
   <total>168</total>
</output>
```

Comment: This looks great Michael! Thank you! Is it still possible to do internal calculations (e.g. choose/when) using this same logic? Apologize for the confusion. I am not adept at XSLT programming.

Comment: Yes, of course. The example is purposefully using a calculation, albeit a simple one. But you can use any process you want to populate the `$subtotals` variable.

Answer (score 0):

**It seems that want you wanted was actually this XSLT transformation** (obtained from the one provided in the problem and fixed a few issues):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <Fact name="TotalLinePrice" factType="Virtual">
    <xsl:variable name="uPrice">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="/PurchaseOrder/LineItems/LineItem/OrderLine" 
                         group-starting-with="OrderLine[normalize-space(OrderQty)]">
               <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                 <xsl:variable name="unitPrice">
                       <xsl:copy-of select="xs:decimal(current-group()/UnitPrice)"/>
                 </xsl:variable>
                 <xsl:variable name="orderQty">
                       <xsl:copy-of select="xs:decimal(current-group()/OrderQty)"/>
                 </xsl:variable>
                 <xsl:variable name="calcPriceBasis">
                     <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='TP']">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 1000))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='HT']">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 1000))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='HP']">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 100))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='HTH']">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 100000))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='PD']">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 12))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='PN']">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 10))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()[UnitPriceBasis='TT']">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="round(($unitPrice div 10000))"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$unitPrice"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                     </xsl:choose>
                 </xsl:variable>
                 <total>
                   <xsl:sequence select=
                     "xs:decimal(format-number($calcPriceBasis * $orderQty, '0.00'))"/>
                 </total>
               </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:copy-of select="sum($uPrice/*)"/>
   </Fact>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above, corrected transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made a well-formed XML document):

```
<PurchaseOrder>
    <LineItems>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>105.28</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>75</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>2.88</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>3</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>155.36</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>12</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>1.64</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>2</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>2.28</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>5</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>3.6</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>405.24</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>5</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>79.04</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>1</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>2.15</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <OrderQty>9</OrderQty>
                <UnitPrice>2.15</UnitPrice>
                <UnitPriceBasis>UM</UnitPriceBasis>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
    </LineItems>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

**the seemingly wanted single result sum is produced**:

```
<Fact name="TotalLinePrice" factType="Virtual">1651.5399999999997</Fact>
```